# Python For each group in DataFrame create a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Trying to create dictionary out of each grouping defined in column `'a'` in python. Below is pandas `DataFrame`.

```
id | day | b | c
-----------------
 A1   1    H   2
 A1   1    C   1
 A1   2    H   3
 A1   2    C   5
 A2   1    H   5
 A2   1    C   6
 A2   2    H   2
 A2   2    C   1
```

**What I am trying to accomplish is a list of dictionaries for each `'id'`:**

```
id A1: [{H: 2, C: 1}, {H: 3, C: 5}]

id A2: [{H: 5, C: 6}, {H: 2, C: 1}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit long ..:-)

```
df.groupby(['id','day'])[['b','c']].apply(lambda x : {t[0]:t[1:][0] for t in x.values.tolist()}).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
Out[815]: 
id
A1    [{'H': 2, 'C': 1}, {'H': 3, 'C': 5}]
A2    [{'H': 5, 'C': 6}, {'H': 2, 'C': 1}]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of dual groupby i.e

```
one = df.groupby(['id','day']).apply(lambda x : dict(zip(x['b'],x['c']))).reset_index()

    id  day                 0
0  A1    1  {'C': 1, 'H': 2}
1  A1    2  {'C': 5, 'H': 3}
2  A2    1  {'C': 6, 'H': 5}
3  A2    2  {'C': 1, 'H': 2}

one.groupby('id')[0].apply(list)

id
A1    [{'C': 1, 'H': 2}, {'C': 5, 'H': 3}]
A2    [{'C': 6, 'H': 5}, {'C': 1, 'H': 2}]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's reshape the dataframe then use `groupby` and `to_dict`:

```
df.set_index(['id','day','b']).unstack()['c']\
  .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
```

Output:

```
id
A1    [{'H': 2, 'C': 1}, {'H': 3, 'C': 5}]
A2    [{'H': 5, 'C': 6}, {'H': 2, 'C': 1}]
dtype: object
```

Comment: We 3 again :-)  LOL

Comment: I was working on `to_dict`, couldn't get it right. This is neat